# SQL Server Browser Start Mode, I can't change the mode because there's nothing in the dropdown

Tags: sql-server-2016

[The red one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXKbs.png)

I can't do the step, because I stopped at this part

Comment: Try running Configuration Manager as admin.

Comment: Or try starting the service through Services.